# How can I install Anydesk desktop?

Tags: software-installation, anydesk

How can I download, install **and open** Anydesk? From the homepage of Anydesk to the Software Center of Ubuntu and installation / download everything is fine but then I couldn't open it.

Comment: If you actually installed it then it can be searched for and opened like any other installed software. Please edit your question and describe what you did to install and what happened when you tried to run it? I just installed (`.deb from Anydesk website) and it works fine.

Comment: Seems like a question for anydesk support.

Answer (score 22):

Through GUI:

- go to https://anydesk.com/platforms
- select your os-compatibility version and install through ubuntu-software-center.

Through CLI:

- `sudo dpkg -i anydesk_2.9.4-1_amd64.deb`
- Install AnyDesk via Ubuntu software center. (Simply open your 'Downloads' folder, right click on `anydesk_2.9.4-1_amd64.deb` choose *Open With Software Install*. Enter your password when it prompted then wait for the AnyDesk installation process to complete.)

Comment: It's better to use `apt` so that possible dependencies get resolved automatically : `sudo apt install ./anydesk_2.9.4-1_amd64.deb`

Comment: Full procedure here: https://overwriteit.com/how-to-install-anydesk-on-ubuntu-the-rite-way/

Answer (score 8):

Better use their repository as suggested [here](http://deb.anydesk.com/howto.html?_ga=2.40850210.1472739393.1586445539-2104800080.1584956681):

**Update as of 22.04 to improve security**

obtain root privileges

```
sudo su
```

To add the key:

```
curl -fsSL https://keys.anydesk.com/repos/DEB-GPG-KEY|sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/anydesk.gpg
```

add the repository:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/anydesk.gpg] http://deb.anydesk.com/ all main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk-stable.list
```

update apt cache:

```
apt update
```

install anydesk:

```
apt install anydesk
```

**Prior answer involving apt-key**

obtain root priviledges

```
sudo su
```

add repository key to Trusted software providers list

```
wget -qO - https://keys.anydesk.com/repos/DEB-GPG-KEY | apt-key add -
```

add the repository:

```
echo "deb http://deb.anydesk.com/ all main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk-stable.list
```

update apt cache:

```
apt update
```

install anydesk:

```
apt install anydesk
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes it does not allow installation from GUI. You can follow below commands:

```
wget https://download.anydesk.com/linux/anydesk_2.9.6-1_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i https://download.anydesk.com/linux/anydesk_2.9.6-1_amd64.deb
```

Now go to that folder in your terminal and use

```
sudo apt install ./anydesk_2.9.6-1_amd64.deb
```

If you have already installed anydesk and want to un-install use bellow command:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove anydesk
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Download Anydesk

   ```
   wget https://download.anydesk.com/linux/anydesk_6.1.0-1_amd64.deb #(may expire)
   ```
2. Install AnyDesk

   Once the download is done, run the command below to instal AnyDesk.

   ```
   sudo apt install -y ./anydesk_5.1.0-1_amd64.deb
   ```

Once the installation is finished AnyDesk will run by default. You can check the status by running the command below;

```
systemctl status anydesk.service
● anydesk.service - AnyDesk
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/anydesk.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-06-11 20:46:50 EAT; 2s ago
Main PID: 4386 (anydesk) Tasks: 12 (limit: 2336)
CGroup: /system.slice/anydesk.service
                   ├─4386 /usr/bin/anydesk --service
                   └─4389 /usr/bin/anydesk --tray

Wax 11 20:46:50 server01.example.com systemd[1]: Started AnyDesk.
```

You have successfully installed AnyDesk on Ubuntu 18.04 desktop. You can now connect to your remote desktop smoothly and securely with AnyDesk. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the following error:

```
E: Unsupported file ./anydesk_5.1.0-1_amd64.deb given on commandline
```

The following commands (as root) worked for me:

```bsh
$ sudo su
$ echo "deb http://deb.anydesk.com/ all main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk-stable.list
$ apt update
$ apt install anydesk
```

Comment: instead of `sudo su`, I suggest beginning each command as sudo. *example:* `sudo echo`... and `sudo apt update`.  This is considerably safer.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to install.

First, download anydesk from anydesk.com. Then run:

```bsh
sudo apt --fix-broken install /tmp/mozilla_user/anydesk_5.5.6-1_amd64.deb
```

Note: Replace `/tmp/mozilla_user` with your download path.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package anydesk (--install):
```

that resolved by:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install ./andydesk.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command

```
sudo apt install anydesk
```

Type password and then when it required permission press Y and then tap enter
and
You are done installing Anydesk

Answer (score 0):

In the first step, you must be a root account *** in UBUNTU

How ?

1. Open the terminal with the same account
2. Type : `sudo passwd root`  ( and press enter)
   enter your user password
   enter your user password again
3. now type :   `su -`  ( and press enter )
4. next Type :   `wget -qO - https://keys.anydesk.com/repos/DEB-GPG-KEY | apt-key add -`
   5.next Type : `echo "deb http://deb.anydesk.com/ all main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk-stable.list`
5. next Type : `apt update`
6. for install enydesk Type :  `apt install anydesk`

Done! :)
have a great day

Answer (score 0):

I had installed anydesk from Ubuntu software. After installation, I opened it in the Ubuntu software itself but couldn't find **Run** button. Only option shown to me was **Remove** button. Also had no idea where the runnable file was so couldn't click anything to run. I think this is also the position of OP.
I ran below command:

```
Locate anydesk
```

It gave me bunch of paths. From which I opened below path in file explorer and double-clicked file anydesk and the app opened.

```
/usr/bin/anydesk
```

Answer (score 0):

https://itsfoss.com/install-anydesk-ubuntu/

or

Open the terminal application on your system. You’ll need a tool like wget to download files in the terminal. For that, use the following command:

1- sudo apt update

2- sudo apt install wget

The next step now is to download the GPG key of AnyDesk repository and add it to your system’s trusted keys. This way, your system will trust the software coming from this external repository.

3- wget -qO - https://keys.anydesk.com/repos/DEB-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -

You may ignore the deprecated warning about apt-key command for now. The next step is to add the AnyDesk repository to your system’s repository sources:

4- echo "deb http://deb.anydesk.com/ all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk-stable.list

Update the package cache so that your system learns about the availability of new applications through the newly added repository.

5- sudo apt update

6- sudo apt install anydesk

7- anydesk