# unable to install anydesk in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

please suggest command to install anydesk in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Anydesk desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893263/how-can-i-install-anydesk-desktop)

Answer (score 1):

You can download installer file from their [website](https://anydesk.com/en/downloads/linux). it's the easiest way, or do it from package manager this will be appreciate , because of update version.

step one update system: `$ sudo apt update`

step two add their public key: `$ wget -qO - https://keys.anydesk.com/repos/DEB-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add -`

step three enable their repository:  `$  echo "deb http://deb.anydesk.com/ all main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/anydesk-stable.list`

finally isntall anydesk: `$ sudo apt install anydesk`